# Four questions about finite fields

Tags: finite-fields

1. Is $\mathbb{F}_5$ a subfield of $\mathbb{F}_7$? I can think of the
   answer 'yes' because they have the same set op operations $+ \cdot$
   and the answer 'no' because in $\mathbb{F}_5: 2\cdot3=1$ and in
   $\mathbb{F}_7: 2\cdot3=6$.
2. When I consider the finite field with four elements $\mathbb{F}_4$:
   $\{0,1,\omega,\omega^2=\omega+1\}$ as being $\mathbb{F}_2 \times
       \mathbb{F}_2$ how do I prove or know that in this field $1+1=0$ like
   in $\mathbb{F}_2$?
   EDIT: by $\mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2$ I mean that the product may be defined in a complicated way, e.g. $(a,b)\cdot(c,d)=(ac+bd,ad+bc+bd)$. Unfortunately I don't know the correct notation.
3. Can it be proved also for the field with 8 elements $\mathbb{F}_8 =
       \mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2\times \mathbb{F}_2$?
4. Is it possible to enumerate the elements of $\mathbb{F}_8$ like an
   extension of the elements of $\mathbb{F}_4$:
   $\{0,1,\omega,\omega^2=\omega+1, \gamma, \gamma^2, \ldots, \delta, \ldots\}
       $

Comment: In what way do $\mathbb{F}_5$ and $\mathbb{F}_7$ have the same operations?

Comment: Note that in $\mathbb F_2\times \mathbb F_2$ you have $(0,1)\cdot (1,0)=(0,0)$ so it isn't a field.

Comment: Notice my edits: you had the curly braces _outside_ of MathJax, thus: {$0,1$}.  I put them _inside_, thus: $\{0,1\}$.  That avoids mismatches in fonts and assures proper spacing and horizontal alignment. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MarkBennet see my edit

Comment: @Gerard: All these are valid questions, great that you are asking.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thanks for pointing out the careless comment which will now be deleted.

Comment: You may also be interested in the Cayley-Dickson construction, which is off the topic of your question, but in the spirit of your edit. If you know JH Conway's work on Nimbers, you will appreciate that this is also related to fields of characteristic 2 and their structure.

Comment: When a field doesnot have any proper ideal how can it have proper subfield?.can somebody answer my question please.

Answer (score 3):

1. No. A finite field  $\mathbf F_{p^m}$ is a subfield of the finite field  $\mathbf F_{q^n}$ if and only if $p=q$  and $m\mid n$.
2. and 3. $\;\mathbf F_2$ is (isomorphic to) a subfield of each of $\mathbf F_{2^m}$, and if $1\cdots 2=0$ in $\mathbf F_2$, it remains true in all $\mathbf F_{2^m}$.

   4. $\;\mathbf F_4 \,$ is not a subfield of  $\;\mathbf F_8$, so your question is meaningless.

Comment: $\mathbf F_8=\mathbf F_{2^3}$. $\mathbf F_4$ is a subfield of $\mathbf F_{16}=\mathbf F_{2^4}$.

Comment: Oops! :) Sorry! Bad arithmetic here! :) I'll delete my comment shortly...

Answer (score 2):

1. If $K\le L$ fields, then $L$ is a *vector space* over $K$, in particular, so $|L|=|K|^{d}$ where $d=\dim_KL$.
2. Start adding $1$ with itself. In a finite ring there's a smallest $n$ such that $n\cdot 1=0$. If the ring has no *zero divisors* then the smallest $n$ must be prime. Note that in case of a field, this set $\{0,1,1+1,\dots\}$ will be a subfield.
3. Yes.
4. Not exactly like that. For $\Bbb F_8$ you need to find an irreducible polynomial of degree $3$, and adjoin its root formally.

Note also that, as rings (or fields) we don't have $\Bbb F_4\cong\Bbb F_2\times\Bbb F_2$ or $\Bbb F_8\cong \Bbb F_2\times\Bbb F_2\times\Bbb F_2$, this is only valid for their underlying additive group.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb F_5$ is definitely not a subfield of $\mathbb F_7$, for the reason you mention.  The operations are not the same operations if they don't have the same values when given the same arguments.

In a field with four elements, you have $1\ne0$, but if $1+1\ne0$, then the set $\{0,1,1+1\}$ contains three of the four elements.  It cannot be a subgroup because $3$ does not divide $4$, or, to put it another way, it would have to have at least one coset consisting of three other elements, and there aren't that many other elements.  So you'd have to have $1+1+1$ as another non-zero element.  Then you would have the problem of what the multiplicative inverse of $1+1$ is.  Notice that $(1+1)^2 = 1+1+1+1$ (by the distributive law), and that $=0$.  If the square of some element is $0$, can that element have a multiplicative inverse?